# Use the result from Cross tab (spark dataframe) for chi-square test in SparkMlib

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I've generated a dataframe `data` from `crosstab` in Spark `DataFrame` and want to perform the chi-squared test.

It seems that `Statistics.chiSqTest` can only be applied to a matrix. My `DataFrame` looks like as below and I want to see whether the level distribution is the same across three groups:

- `true`
- `false`
- and `Undefined`.

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics


+-----------------------------+-------+--------+----------+
|levels                       |   true|   false|Undefined |
+-----------------------------+-------+--------+----------+
|                         1   |32783  |634460  |2732340   |
|                         2   | 2139  | 41248  |54855     |
|                         3   |28837  |573746  |5632147   |
|                         4   |16473  |320529  |8852552   |
+-----------------------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Is there any easy way to transform this in order to be used for chi-squared test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to handle this without using `mllib.Statistics`:

```
import scipy.stats

crosstab = ...  
scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(
  crosstab.drop(crosstab.columns[0]).toPandas().as_matrix()
)
```

If you really want Spark statistics:

```
from itertools import chain

Statistics.chiSqTest(DenseMatrix(
    numRows=crosstab.count(), numCols=len(crosstab.columns) - 1, 
    values=list(chain(*zip(*crosstab.drop(crosstab.columns[0]).collect())))
))
```